# solving for the phase plane equation help?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I am studying for a dif. eq. exam and came across the following problems:

solve the phase plane equation for the given system

a) $\frac{dx}{dt}=y-1$, $\frac{dy}{dt}=e^{x+y}$

This is how I did it the first time:

1. $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{e^{x+y}}{y-1}$
2. $(y-1)dy=e^{x+y}dx$
3. $\frac{1}{2}y^2-y=e^{x+y}+c$
4. $e^{x+y}-\frac{1}{2}y^2+y=c$

However the books answer key showed it differently so I redid it to match the book:

1. $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{e^{x+y}}{y-1}=\frac{e^xe^y}{y-1}$
2. $\frac{(y-1)}{e^y}dy=e^xdx$
3. $\frac{y}{e^y}+\frac{1}{e^y}-\frac{1}{e^y}=e^x+c$
4. $e^x+\frac{y}{e^y}=c$

So is the first way actually wrong or are they both technically correct?

b) $\frac{dx}{dt}=2y-x$, $\frac{dy}{dt}=e^x+y$

1. $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{e^x+y}{2y-x}$
2. $(2y-x)dy=(e^x+y)dx$
3. $y^2-xy=e^x+xy$
4. $e^x+2xy+y^2=c$

But the book shows it as $e^x+xy+y^2=c$ so did I do something wrong?

Comment: When you integrate in this way, you must have all y's on one side and all x's on the other side. You can't mix and match as you do in several of the cases above.

Comment: @barrycarter, how do you get the solution for b then? $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is not separable...

Comment: OK, this doesn't answer your question, but remember than x is a function of t, and y is a function of t, so x is implicitly a function of y and vice versa. In other words, when you integrate x dy you don't get x y, because x is a function of y, not a constant. In this case, try taking the mixed partial with respect to t for both parametric equations and setting them equal (not sure that'll work, but maybe).

Comment: I think what you are saying is find if they are exact equations, which they are not. Also shouldn't I be able to take the partials of $e^x+xy+y^2$ and get $\frac{dx}{dt}$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}$ because it doesn't work out.

Comment: In this specific case, if you differentiate dx/dt again you get `2*dy/dt - dx/dt = 2*(e^x+y) - (2y + x) = 2*e^x + x`. By integrating twice and figuring out constants, I think you can solve x(t) explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case a :

You can see on the screen-copy where the mistake exactly is :

[image]

Case b :

Again :

[image]

You have to integrate only EXACT differentials :

$$(2y-x)dy=(e^x+y)dx$$
$$2ydy-xdy=e^xdx+ydx$$
$$2ydy=e^xdx+xdy+ydx$$
$$d(y^2)=d(e^x)+d(xy)$$
because $d(xy)=xdy+ydx$
$$y^2=e^x+xy+\text{constant}$$

Comment: I have never seen the syntax $d(xy)$ before can you clarify this?

Comment: @ JDOdle : This is the usual symbol for exact differential. See the definition in : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExactDifferential.html

Comment: I like this answer because I can pretend it's what I said (and it sort of is, but written much better than I wrote it).